Geometry nodes simulation doesn't show in render
I'm trying to learn VFX in blender and decided to place my geometry node simulation inside a video.
Unfortunately, despite everything working fine in viewport, the simulated object doesn't show in render and I have no idea why.
I've tried: baking the simulation.
I attach related images of my scene below. Thanks in advance kind strangers!


(below are the elements of my scene)




Have you rendered the scene? Because the Render Layers node does not show a preview above it. Even if the scene would have been rendered empty, there would have been an empty preview. Did you hit F12 to render only a single still image or Ctrl+F12 to render an animation over the movie?

In the top tab, I pressed render and render image; is there a different way that would give me better results? Also, I did some testing and it seems like the issue is not in geometry nodes nor simulations. A simple cube also doesn't show in render. Do you have an idea why?

Are there any informations missing in your question? For example, do you have a strip in the Video Sequence Editor (the movie clip for example)? See here: Effects are shown in 'Compositing' but won't render or here: Render result is completely blank
